# Ajax Jquery in PHPMailer SMTP

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

I have a problem in using phpmailer using ajax jquery. It will not send email to my recipient please help me here are the codes:

For my popupjob.php where it will process my ajax:
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.submit').click(function(){

```
        for (var a=0; a < document.checkform.jobclient.length; a++)
            {
                if (document.checkform.jobclient[a].checked){
                    var agentId = document.checkform.jobclient[a].value;
                    var dataString = 'action=sendMail&companyId=<?=$_SESSION['ses_companyid']?>&agentId=' + agentId; 
                    $.ajax({
                    cache: 'false',
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "ajaxfunction.php",  
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(msg){

                        }
                    }); 
                }
            }
});
```

});

My problem really is in my ajax.php. It will not send my email to the email address I inputted.

```
function func12(){

include('adodb/adodb.inc.php'); 
include "include/manager_shared.php";

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>PHPMailer - SMTP basic test with authentication</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    error_reporting(E_STRICT);

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

    require_once('include/class.phpmailer.php');
    //include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

    $mail             = new PHPMailer();

    $body             = file_get_contents('include/contents.html');
    $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
     // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                               // 1 = errors and messages
                                               // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPSecure= "ssl";
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "username@domain"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "mypassword";        // SMTP account password

    $mail->SetFrom('username@domain', 'First Last');

    $mail->AddReplyTo("username@domain","First Last");

    $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $address = "johnDoe@gmail.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    } 
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

```
switch($_POST['action']){
    case 'sendMail':
        $output = func12();
        break;
    default:
        $output = '';
} 

echo $output;
```

}

?>

Please help me. Replies are much appreciated........By the way I am using facebox in pop-upping my form. Thanks

Comment: You didn't give us enough context - there seems to be error handling in your "codes". Do you get any output? Any error messages at all? In the error log? On the mailserver? What happens when you call the PHP script normally (not through AJAX)?

Comment: thanks Piskvor for the reply, it seems that the problem is in the mail->Send(), I can 't get any output, no error has been displayed, the mailserver has no problem, and whend I call it manually, it process the php...please help me....

Comment: Thanks Piskvor, I already solve the problem, the problem is I did not put the class class.smtp.php..... anyways, thank you for the time